# How to Plot Data With Python Using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am able to plot with simple arrays like range(10) but when I try with data I load from the stock market, my code fails to plot the data.

This is the output of the below code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tljfv.png

I know this code is fetching the data properly because it prints. Please let me know if you can help or have any pointers.

```
# importing the required module
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import requests
import requests
filename = '/mnt/c/Users/jaspe/Documents/GitHub/python/uglek-stocks/output.png'
api_key = '<<APIKEYHERE>>'
symbol = 'TSLA'
url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=' + symbol + '&apikey=' + api_key
print(url)

# fetch stock data
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
# get time series
ts = data['Time Series (Daily)']

# y axis values
y = [0] * 100

count = 0
for d in ts:
    # get daily price
    value = int(float(ts[d]['1. open']))
    y[count] = value # assign to y value
    count + count + 1
# plotting the points
plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(range(100), y)
# naming the x and y axis
plt.ylabel('Open')
plt.xlabel('Days')
# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('TSLA')
# save to file
plt.savefig(filename)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the values correctly? Also, are you sure the "problem" is not your data? Maybe the first value is too big and you need a log scale to really see the others.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `count + count + 1`, what do you think this should mean, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, we don't usually need 'counter' variables like that, but if that's what you're used to, then you should update it in your loop. Currently you have

```
counter + counter + 1
```

but I think you meant

```
counter += 1
```

This should fix your problem assuming your `value` variable is retrieved from your data structure correctly.

The more pythonic way to use a counter is to use `enumerate` like so:

```
for i, d in enumerate(ts.keys()):
    value = int(float(ts[d]['1. open']))
    y[i] = value # assign to y value
```

or even better, use a list comprehension

```
y = [int(float(ts[d]['1. open'])) for d in ts.keys()]
x = range(len(y))
plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Note: the above alternatives are untested, and debugging them for your data may lead you to other SO questions.